# How to derive the form of transformation operators in Einstein notation?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, covariance

I've been reading through MWT to try and drill home some of the fundamentals a little more. I've gotten to their derivation of the form of Lorentz Transformation in Einstein notation and how they act on vectors components and 1-forms but I feel a little disconnected from how they started the book with thinking about the abstract objects. My thinking would be the following:

1. We have abstract objects like vectors
   $$
   x = x^\mu \bar{e_\mu},
   $$
   that can be represented in different coordinate frames:
   $$
   x = x^{\mu'} \bar{e_{\mu'}}.
   $$
2. We want an operator $\Lambda$ which maps coordinates of the vector in the unprimed basis to the primed basis:
   $$
   \Lambda : x^\mu \to x^{\mu'}
   $$
3. We also want $\Lambda$ to have in inverse:
   $$
   \Lambda^{-1} :  x^{\mu'}\to x^\mu 
   $$

To this point I would be fine but where I'm a little lost in how to show the components of this operator can be written as:
$$
\Lambda^{\mu'}_{\ \ \mu}, \ \Lambda^{\mu}_{\ \ \mu'}, \text{ s.t } x^{\mu'} = \Lambda^{\mu'}_{\ \ \mu} x^\mu
$$

I suppose my confusion comes down to 2 points

1. The up-down choice of the indicies. I assume the idea is that we say that the original coordinate transformed like a vector component and so we need the output to also transform like a vector component. Thus, we need to trace over the old up-stairs indicie with a down-stairs indicie and have the remaining indicie also be up-stairs?
2. Why do we choose/know that the transformation should be linear? Is it not possible to have the transformation be quadratic in $x^\mu$?
3. Is it possible to find the form of the components of $\Lambda$ by looking at how it acts on basis vectors or something of the sort?
4. I've had the basics of GR taught so many times in different courses I have a hard time of knowing which ideas I can use as fundamentals and which are actually derived ideas from the things I want to prove.